# How can I get breakpoints/logs/increased visibility when my Main Thread blocks?

Tags: ios, multithreading, macos, debugging, io

In the never-ending quest for UI responsiveness, I would like to gain more insight into cases where the main thread performs blocking operations.

I'm looking for some sort of "debugging mode" or extra code, or hook, or whatever, whereby I can set a breakpoint/log/something that will get hit and allow me to inspect what's going if my main thread "voluntarily" blocks for I/O (or whatever reason, really) other than for going idle at the end of the runloop.

In the past, I've looked at runloop cycle wall-clock duration using a runloop observer, and that's valuable for seeing the problem, but by the time you can check, it's too late to get a good idea for what it was doing, because your code is already done running for that cycle of the runloop.

I realize that there are operations performed by UIKit/AppKit that are main-thread-only that will cause I/O and cause the main thread to block so, to a certain degree, it's hopeless (for instance, accessing the pasteboard appears to be a potentially-blocking, main-thread-only operation) but something would be better than nothing.

Anyone have any good ideas?  Seems like something that would be useful.  In the ideal case, you'd never want to block the main thread while your app's code is active on the runloop, and something like this would be very helpful in getting as close to that goal as possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I set forth to answer my own question this weekend.  For the record, this endeavor turned into something pretty complex, so like Kendall Helmstetter Glen suggested, most folks reading this question should probably just muddle through with Instruments. For the masochists in the crowd, read on!

It was easiest to start by restating the problem. Here's what I came up with:

> I want to be alerted to long periods of time spent in
>   syscalls/mach_msg_trap that are not legitimate idle time.  "Legitimate
>   idle time" is defined as time spent in mach_msg_trap waiting for the
>   next event from the OS.

Also importantly, I didn't care about user code that takes a long time. That problem is quite easy to diagnose and understand using Instruments' Time Profiler tool. I wanted to know specifically about blocked time.  While it's true that you can also diagnose blocked time with Time Profiler, I've found it considerably harder to use for that purpose. Likewise, the System Trace Instrument is also useful for investigations like this, but is extremely fine grained and complex.  I wanted something simpler -- more targetted to this specific task.

It seemed evident from the get-go that the tool of choice here would be Dtrace. 
I started out by using a `CFRunLoop` observer that fired on `kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting` and `kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting`. A call to my `kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting` handler would indicate the beginning of a "legitimate idle time" and the `kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting` handler would be the signal to me that a legitimate wait had ended.  I would use the Dtrace pid provider to trap on calls to those functions as a way to sort legitimate idle from blocking idle.

This approach got me started, but in the end proved to be flawed. The biggest problem is that many AppKit operations are *synchronous*, in that they block event processing in the UI, but actually spin the RunLoop lower in the call stack. Those spins of the RunLoop are not "legitimate" idle time (for my purposes), because the user can't interact with the UI during that time. They're valuable, to be sure -- imagine a runloop on a background thread watching a bunch of RunLoop-oriented I/O -- but the UI is still blocked when this happens on the main thread. For example, I put the following code into an IBAction and triggered it from a button:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com/"] 
                                                   cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                               timeoutInterval: 60.0];    
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* err = nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: req returningResponse: &response error: &err];
```

That code doesn't prevent the RunLoop from spinning -- AppKit spins it for you inside the `sendSynchronousRequest:...` call --  but it does prevent the user from interacting with the UI until it returns. This is not "legitimate idle" to my mind, so I needed a way to sort out which idles were which. (The `CFRunLoopObserver` approach was also flawed in that it requred changes to the code, which my final solution does not.)

I decided that I would model my UI/main thread as a state machine. It was in one of three states at all times: LEGIT_IDLE, RUNNING or BLOCKED, and would transition back and forth between those states as the program executed. I needed to come up with Dtrace probes that would allow me to catch (and therefore measure) those transitions. The final state machine I implemented was quite a bit more complicated than just those three states, but that's the 20,000 ft view.

As described above, sorting out legitimate idle from bad idle was not straightforward, since both cases end up in `mach_msg_trap()` and `__CFRunLoopRun`. I couldn't find one simple artifact in the call stack that I could use to reliably tell the difference; It appears that a simple probe on one function is not going to help me. I ended up using the debugger to look at the state of the stack at various instances of legitimate idle vs. bad idle.  I determined that during legitimate idle, I'd (seemingly reliably) see a call stack like this:

```
#0  in mach_msg
#1  in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
#2  in __CFRunLoopRun
#3  in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#4  in RunCurrentEventLoopInMode
#5  in ReceiveNextEventCommon
#6  in BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode
#7  in _DPSNextEvent
#8  in -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
#9  in -[NSApplication run]
#10 in NSApplicationMain
#11 in main
```

So I endeavored to set up a bunch of nested/chained pid probes that would establish when I had arrived at, and subsequently left, this state.  Unfortunately, for whatever reason Dtrace's pid provider doesn't seem to be universally able to probe both entry and return on all arbitrary symbols.  Specifically, I couldn't get probes on `pid000:*:__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort:return` or on `pid000:*:_DPSNextEvent:return` to work. The details aren't important, but by watching various other goings on, and keeping track of certain state, I was able to establish (again, seemingly reliably) when I was entered and left the legit idle state.

Then I had to determine probes for telling the difference between RUNNING and BLOCKED. That was a bit easier. In the end, I chose to consider BSD system calls (using Dtrace's syscall probe) and calls to `mach_msg_trap()` (using the pid probe) not occurring in periods of legit idle to be BLOCKED. (I did look at Dtrace's mach_trap probe, but it did not seem to do what I wanted, so I fell back to using the pid probe.)

Initially, I did some extra work with the Dtrace sched provider to actually measure *real* blocked time (i.e. time when my thread had been suspended by the scheduler) but that added considerable complexity, and I ended up thinking to myself, "If I'm in the kernel, what do I care if the thread is actually asleep or not? It's all the same to the user: it's blocked." So the final approach just measures all time in `(syscalls || mach_msg_trap()) && !legit_idle` and calls that the blocked time.

At this point, catching single kernel calls of long duration (like a call to `sleep(5)` for instance) is rendered trivial. However, more often UI thread latency comes from many little latencies accumulating over multiple calls into the kernel (think of hundreds of calls to read() or select()), so I thought it would also be desirable to dump SOME call stack when the overall amount of syscall or `mach_msg_trap` time in a single pass of the event loop exceeded a certain threshold. I ended up setting up various timers and logging accumulated time spent in each state, scoped to various states in the state machine, and dumping alerts when we happened to be transitioning out of the BLOCKED state, and had gone over some threshold. This method will obviously produce data that is subject to misinterpretation, or might be a total red herring (i.e. some random, relatively quick syscall that just happens to push us over the alert threshold), but I feel like it's better than nothing.

In the end, the Dtrace script ends up keeping a state machine in D variables, and uses the described probes to track transitions between the states and gives me the opportunity to do things (like print alerts) when the state machine is transitioning state, based on certain conditions. I played around a bit with a contrived sample app that does a bunch of disk I/O, network I/O, and calls sleep(), and was able to catch all three of those cases, without distractions from data pertaining to legitimate waits. This was exactly what I was looking for.

This solution is obviously quite fragile, and **thoroughly awful** in almost every regard. :) It may or may not be useful to me, or anyone else, but it was a fun exercise, so I thought I'd share the story, and the resulting Dtrace script. Maybe someone else will find it useful.  I also must confess being a relative `n00b` with respect to writing Dtrace scripts so I'm sure I've done a million things wrong.  Enjoy!

It was too big to post in line, so it's kindly being hosted by @Catfish_Man over here: [MainThreadBlocking.d](http://dscoder.com/MainThreadBlocking.d)

Comment: I haven't tried running this yet, but regardless if it works or not, this is probably the best stack overflow answer I've seen. My one quibble is that I can't seem to get the download site you're hosting that on to do anything but download a .exe; not terribly useful on OSX ;)

Answer (score 1):

Really this is the kind of job for the Time Profiler instrument.  I believe you can see where time is spent in code per thread, so you'd go see what code was taking a while to perform and get the answer as to what was potentially blocking UI.